# Use python to determine what element(s) a value is in

Tags: python, xml

I've tried searching for this in every way I can think, but have had no luck. I apologize in advance if this has been asked an answered in a different way.

What I need help accomplishing:

I have a set of name values like: ['John Smith', 'New York', 'Toys'] and I know they exist in an XML document, something like:

```
<doc>
    <people>
        <name>John Smith</name>
    </people>
    <places>
        <name>New York</name>
    </places>
    <things>
        <name>Toys</name>
    </things>
    <about>
       <name>John Smith is male.</name>
    </about>
</doc>
```

Using elementtree, I can loop through the list and find those values in the document.

What I'm trying to figure out how to do as the title states is:

1. Loop through the list and find the values in the document
2. Figure out what XML tag(s) is/are around each value and return the tag name

I can't figure this out, but I imagine there must be a way to accomplish this without too much heavy lifting. Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ ... I have a hard time believeing you searched very hard ... did you actually try anything?

Comment: A bit harsh, but maybe that's not your intention. I did search and I did try many things. I have actually been toying with this for several days. I'm no python expert and clearly no expert at crafting a search query that would surface what I needed (and I did try BeautifulSoup but ran into the same issue). It turns out my real issue was how to properly nest my loops to bring back what I needed. I'm glad there are helpful folks here on Stack Overflow and am always grateful to them. Perhaps this will help someone as unbelievable as me in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't tied to elementtree, here is a simple example using `lxml` (note: I didn't do the loops for you, you can do that portion of the work).  But it will get you the tag that contains the text, then the parent of that tag:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from lxml import etree

lines = None
with open('ex.xml') as f:
    lines = f.read()

doc = etree.fromstring(lines)
elem = doc.xpath("//name[text()='John Smith']")

for e in elem:
    parent = e.getparent()
    print(parent.tag)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Using re.findall

```
re.findall('<name>(.*)</name>', string )
```

Comment: Whwre this name tag gone

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, there are 2 enumerated items.  1 you get, 2 you aren't addressing.

Comment: yep i submited the ans through stackexchange app, it dosent let me insert name tag, now i have edited from my laptop

Comment: Still missing part 2, they want to know where the tag is in the tree.  Regex isn't the right solution to parsing html/xml documents reliably.  If they just wanted the text - it works fine - but when you want to traverse the tree - it's a little rough.

Comment: I should have specified that I might not know the name of the tag. nerdwaller's example helps with that. Thank you for making an effort to answer though.